# Setting minimumVersionCode in Application Policy returns 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: android-management-api

Since i want to force an update to my kiosk devices, this feature seems mandatory.
So i was wondering if this is just me or this is a temporary issue, effecting all.

The 503 occurs when patching a policy with "minimumVersionCode" in the Application Policy Part.

If anybody has any insights on this, your answers are very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it has been fixed by now. It works!